# Popup Cookie Wordpress select language and section (Elementor)

Tags: plugins, multi-language, cookies

I need to show a popup where the user can choose the language and which section to open (partners, customers, support) and that this choice is kept in the cookies so that the next time he returns that section and the selected language are opened directly, but I don't know how to do this, any ideas? (create the popup if I know how to do it but not how to add this selection and save it)

1. Add Language switch in the popup (modal).
2. Whatever language selection user made should be stored in Cookie and next time he/she opens, site should open in that specific language saved in it.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to create a modal pop up with these parameters.
after that you can use cookie js.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/js-cookie@2.2.1/src/js.cookie.min.js"></script>
```

Remember that you need to include jquery before loading this js.
For further details you can refer to https://github.com/js-cookie/js-cookie

After including above js and Jquery in your code. You can directly use `Cookies.set('foo', 'bar')` to set a cookie with name `foo` and can access it by `Cookies.get('foo')`

Now it depends on you how you use it in your program.